# JVM Proxy configuration for RestTemplate - apache HttpClientBuilder

Tags: java, spring-boot, proxy, resttemplate, jvm-arguments

I'm stuck with this proxy configuration. I'm using RestTemplate and I need to apply proxy for all the calls that RestTemplate makes. I'm trying to utilize JVM arguments because, I really need proxy for my local dev box.

**Code:**

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class RestTemplateProxy {

    public static void main(String...strings) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperties());
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(5000)
                .setConnectTimeout(2000)
                .build();
        HttpClient defaultHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager)
                        .build();

        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(200);
        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(200);
        ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(defaultHttpClient);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);

        String res = restTemplate.getForObject("API URL.....", String.class);
        System.out.println(res);

    }

}
```

**How validated:**

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=1212 -Dhttps.proxyPort=1212
```

In a non proxy environment, I used proxy host to localhost -> It should failed to connect. Instead it's bypassing the configurations and trying to reach the service and getting the response.

**System Arguments Print:**

```
https.proxyHost=localhost, http.proxyPort=1212, http.proxyHost=localhost, https.proxyPort=1212
```

Answer (score 0):

To make Apache HttpClient use the proxy settings passed using VM args, you'll have to call `.useSystemProperties()` while building the HTTP Client.

```
HttpClient defaultHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
.useSystemProperties()
.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
.setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager).build();
```